# How to open Image manager through Enterprise Architect API

Tags: c#, image, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect through C# add-ins. I need to display the image manager through automation where user can add directly add images on an "add image" button click in form.

I use the API Repository.InvokeConstructPicker() but it only opens the select package/class/component window. Is there an EA API available to open the Image Manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing the image to image manager from add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605021/importing-the-image-to-image-manager-from-add-in)

Comment: @Arshad I was asking if there is any EA API available for displaying the image manager dialog similar to the API given above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is none. There is the undocumented `Respository.CustomCommand` which can open several properties windows. But the image manager is not part of that (or it has not been discovered what parameters to supply).

Please see Edit2 below about adding new values to the table.

**Edit**: Based on another question I had to dig into this a bit deeper.

I found out that, although EA imports a number of different image formats, it internally uses PNG to store the image. Obviously their BMP-importer does not like all BMP formats (not so deep in that, but I seem to remember there's some 8/16 bit stuff; typical Windoze weirdness). Anyhow, I used this Python code snippet to retrieve some test image data, previously imported into EA:

```
import sys
import win32com.client
import base64
import xml.etree.ElementTree

eaRep = None
try:
    eaApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject(Class="EA.App")
    eaRep = eaApp.repository
except:
    print "failure to open EA"
    sys.exit(2)

def dump():
    sqlRes = eaRep.SQLQuery("SELECT * FROM t_image")
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(sqlRes)
    for dataset in root:
        for data in dataset:
            for row in data:
                name = row[1].text
                print name
                data = row[3].text
                png = base64.standard_b64decode(data)
                file = open("c:/" + name + ".png", "wb")
                file.write(png)
                file.close()

dump()
```

This correctly extracted the images from the database.

**Edit2**: I was assuming that EA stores the png as base64, but that's not true. EA only delivers base64 on return of `SQLQuery`. But they internally just store the raw png in `Image`. So, unfortunately, you can not use `Repository.Execute` since it can not transport binary data - or at least I have not figured out how to do that. As a work around you can look into `Repository.ConnectionString` and open a native connection to the database. Once you have plugged the new picture(s) in the table you can use them via thier `ImageID`.

Contents of `t_image`:

- `ImageID` : You just need to create an unique ID
- `Name` : an arbitrary string
- `Type` : fixed string *Bitmap*
- `Image` : blob of a png

Here's a Python snippet that connects natively to an EAP file:

```
import pyodbc
db_file = r'''C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\empty.eap'''

odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=' + db_file
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from t_image")
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)
```

Rather than printing the row with the image data (which shows that its contents is a png-blob) you can use it to actually issue an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to modify `t_image`.