# Enterprise Architect API for Adding Image to Image Manager

Tags: c#, image, element, enterprise-architect

I am working on forms in Enterprise Architect C# add-ins. I need to add images to the image manager through automation because by setting hyperlink to them in element/package notes, I am able export the images to external path using the EA API Repository.ExtractImagesFromNote ().

In common toolbox, there is an image element. On dragging and dropping it automatically opens the image manager to set an alternate image to it. I also noticed that this image was not displayed in the project browser (is it because it is a non-UML element?).

I tried adding this image element through automation as shown below:

```
EA.Element testImg = viewPkg.Elements.AddNew(imagePath, "Image")
```

The elements gets created as shown :

[image]

It had created an image asset ( from the artifacts toolbox) and not the image element (from the common toolbox).

I need the image to be added to image manager. I request help for creating image element from common toolbox and setting an image to it through code instead of the image asset.

I also noticed this option in Image Manager:

[image]

Current Code for updating t_image table:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Figure 1.1.bmp"));
Session.Repository.Execute("INSERT INTO t_image VALUES('0000000002','test200','Bitmap','"+base64+ "')");
```

[image]
[image]

I have updated the code as below for converting image in .png to base64 encoded string

```
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(img, new Size(img.Width / 5,  img.Height / 5));
resized.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Png);
imageStream.Position = 0;
var imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

I am inserting this value to the t_image table using the repository.execute command:

```
 Session.Repository.Execute("INSERT INTO t_image VALUES(" + imgCount + ",'" + imgPath+".bmp" + "','Bitmap','"+ImageBase64+"')");
```

Comment: You want to programatically add image to image manager in EA ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing the image to image manager from add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605021/importing-the-image-to-image-manager-from-add-in)

Comment: @Arshad thank you..I referred it previously. I want to use the image element from common toolbox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that does is actually creating an `<<image>> Artifact` (or you can use a `Boundary`) and assigning an alternate image to it. The image needs to be placed in EA's image library. You can read in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903306/how-to-open-image-manager-through-enterprise-architect-api/50904686#50904686) how to achieve that.

Comment: Uhhhh! I think I got it. The contents is probably a blob and they only return base64 with SQLQuery. So it needs to be put raw into the table. But the Repository.Execute would fail. Hmmmmm. I have to install a couple of things to test that.

Comment: I indirectly have verified that t_image just contains the raw .png. So in order to access that, you need to go via a native database driver. I'll edit the linked answer. P.S. please also cleat your part of the chat.

Comment: Thank you Thomas..I will work on it..I cleared the chat as well.

Comment: Hi Thomas ..trying to connect to EA database this way.. string eastring = Session.Repository.ConnectionString;
                bool isOpen = Session.Repository.OpenFile(eastring);               My doubt is, even if I am able to fetch a diagramobject here and try to set an image to it then ImageId must be set.                                                    For this the imageId must be available in t_image table. So wont it all come back to image being available in image manager. Got confused here. Plaese help.

Comment: Basically yes, you need to put in the image into t_image first (using native DB access). Once you got it into t_image you can return to EA's API to set the alternate image.

Comment: Hi Thomas..been trying to connect to database and facing few problems with that..can you kindly provide some reference links/code for the connecting to native database in EA.:-(

Comment: What kind of RDBMS are you using? EAP?

Comment: we are using the file based repository (EAP-MS Access)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to use an ODBC-adpater and feed in the string from `Repository.ConnectionString`, should it? (Honestly I currently do have problems since I'm using wine now after my Parallels broke.) Maybe you could open another question for that?